# Is it possible to add baremetal server as a AWS EKS woker node?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, hybrid-cloud

I'm in the process of building a hybrid Kubernetes cluster, where the control plane is hosted on AWS EKS (Elastic Kubernetes Service) and managed by AWS. I'm interested in adding one of my local bare metal servers as a worker node to this EKS cluster. Is it possible to integrate bare metal servers as AWS EKS worker nodes, and if so, what steps do I need to follow to achieve this configuration?

In researching this topic so far I've only found resources on EKS via AWS Outposts, EKS Anywhere, joining federated clusters, etc. -- but it seems these solutions involve managing our own infrastructure, losing the benefits of fully-managed EKS on AWS. I can't find any information about extending AWS-managed EKS clusters with on-prem hardware (effectively allowing AWS to take ownership of the node/system and integrate it into the cluster).

Comment: maybe this can help you https://aws.amazon.com/eks/eks-anywhere/

Answer (score 0):

You already mentioned the solution you are looking for - [AWS EKS Anywhere](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/eks-anywhere/). It does exactly what you want.